# merge flask_socketio into my own flask project

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio, flask-script

I developed my restful api flask project (let's call it 'MYOWN').

And then, because of some needs to implement functions like 'notification', 'chat', and so on, I tried to merge my project with simple [socketIO example project](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/tree/master/example).

I want to run my project with only one command below

```
> ./manage.py runserver
```

In 'MYOWN's manage.py script, there exist

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    manager.run()
```

and it made me confused with "where do I insert script below to 'MYOWN'?".

```
socketio.run(app)
```

Is there any way to run 'MYOWN' and [socketIO example project](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/tree/master/example) same time?

Answer (score 0):

Flask-Script's `runserver` command is not compatible with Flask-SocketIO. If you want to start your server with Flask-Script you have to write a new version of `runserver`. A simple replacement could be:

```
@manager.command
def runserver():
    socketio.run()
```

Of course you can add any arguments you need, but not that some of the arguments are different between `app.run()` and `socketio.run`.